# Problem about partial derivatives

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

I have two problems:

Let $$f : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}, f \in C^2$$.

**Problem 1**

Find all functions such that 
$$\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x \partial y} = 0$$

**Problem 2**

Find all functions such that 
$$\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial^2 x} = \frac{\partial^2f}{\partial ^2y}$$

**Attempt to 1**

We have by integration

$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = c(x)$, where $c(x)$ is a function of $x$ only.
Then $f(x, y) = \int c(x) + h(y)$, where $h(y)$ is a function of $y$ only. Since $c(x)$ is arbitrary, we can set 
$f(x, y) = c_2(x) + h(y)$ with the condition that $c_2(x)$ is derivable.
Is it enough?

**Attempt to 2**

Here I'm quite stuck.
I know there are some class of functions that works
(like $f(x, y) = k_1(x^2 + y^2) + k_2x + k_3 y + k_4$)) 
but how to find them all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proof for Problem 1 seems fine to me.

Moreover, I believe Problem 2 is a PDE, and you cannot solve it trivially. It is a hyperbolic PDE, exactly the canonical form of the wave equation: given $u(t,x)$, $u$ is such that
$$
u_{tt}-v^2u_{xx}=0,
$$
$$
u(x,0)=\phi_0(t),
$$
$$
u_t(x,0)=\phi_1(t).
$$
The general solution is given by D'Alembert, who said that:
$$
u(x,t)=\frac{1}{2}(\phi_0(x-vt)+\phi_0(x+vt))+\frac{1}{2v}\int_{x-vt}^{x+vt}\phi_1(s)ds.
$$
In your case $v^2=1$. Thus:
$$
u(x,y)=\frac{1}{2}(\phi_0(x-y)+\phi_0(x+y))+\frac{1}{2}\int_{x-y}^{x+y}\phi_1(s)ds
$$

Comment: thanks. I haven't studied PDE so I'm probably just gonna skip the second :)

Comment: You can also pose $\xi=x+y$ and $\psi=x-y$ and fin that $\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial\xi\partial\psi}=0$, so that you can use your previous result, without interpreting it as a PDE. So that every sum as such of $f(x+y)+g(x-y)$ is a solution of Problem 2.

Comment: nice! But if you change the variables that way how do you find the resulting expression of $\frac{\partial ^2 u}{\partial \xi \partial \psi}$?

Comment: Exactly in the same way as before: $u(\xi,\psi)=f(\xi)+g(\psi)$

Comment: ahah right, of course.. thanks again :)